# Document for the parsed instruction data of transferChecked

Tags: rpc, jsonrpc-api, decode

I would like to know where the document for the parsed instruction data returned from RPC:getBlock with encoding=jsonParsed for Token/Token-2022 program. Or where is the "program-specific instruction parser" located in those programs written in Rust?

Quote from the Solana-RPC document:

> "jsonParsed" encoding attempts to use program-specific instruction parsers to return more human-readable and explicit data ...

Now the way I tried is making an RPC and assuming the response body covers all fields that instruction might return. For example, below is the partial result of "transferChecked" instruction I got.

```
{
  "info": {
    "authority": "pk0",
    "destination": "pk1",
    "mint": "token-addr-0",
    "source": "pk-2",
    "tokenAmount": {
      "amount": "200000000",
      "decimals": 8,
      "uiAmount": 2,
      "uiAmountString": "2"
    }
  },
  "type": "transferChecked"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find all of the instruction parsers in the `solana-transaction-status` crate, and here's the implementation for token: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/transaction-status/src/parse_token.rs

In case you need it, the account decoders are in `solana-account-decoder`, and here's the token implementation https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/account-decoder/src/parse_token.rs